# Xarray computing of a new variable on the basis of the existing one

Tags: python, netcdf, xarray, noaa

I have netcdf file with calculated average temperature (°F). My goal is to create new data variable within the same file with cooling / heating degree days using that average. This format is totally new for me and is hard to figure out solution.
I've tried assign new data variable using following syntax but without expecting results. I guess it because is taking into calculation whole array at once.

```
nc = nc.assign(cdd_hdd=lambda x: x.tavg - 65 if tavg > 65 else 65 - x.tavg)
```

My goal:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 360, lon: 720, time: 259)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 89.75 89.25 88.75 88.25 ... -88.75 -89.25 -89.75
  * lon      (lon) float32 0.25 0.75 1.25 1.75 2.25 ... 358.2 358.8 359.2 359.8
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-01-01 2022-01-02 ... 2022-09-16
Data variables:
    tavg     (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    cdd_hdd     (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new variables to an existing `xr.Dataset` by adding a new "key" to the dataset, with the value being a `xr.DataArray` :

```
nc["cdd_hdd"] = xr.where(nc["tavg"] > 65, nc["tavg"] - 65, 65 - nc["tavg"])
```

`xr.where` takes three arguments, first is a condition, second are the values at coordinates where the condition is `True`, third are values where the condition is `False`.

Comment: The NetCDF file must be opened in read/write mode.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71790020/1211981

Comment: Thanks Bert! , once again you're saving my day.

Comment: feel free to accept the answer ;) @nomad_gis